# MathCalc - Expression calculator in React js

Tags: reactjs, calculator

Good morning,
How could I turn [this object](https://gist.github.com/paiv/9490c20e6d985f512fab) into a usable component in React JS?
I try to use it but I get multiple errors.

Link: [MathCalc - Expression calculator in JavaScript](https://paiv.github.io/blog/2016/03/23/js-calc.html)

I use ESLint and the code changes when trying to create the component. I fixed bugs, but I can't get it to work properly.

In a new project without ESLint I manage to use it with the ambiguous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an [expression-calculator](https://github.com/frank-deng/expression-calculator) npm package.